# (oracle) why user has not [alter session] privilege but can alter session

Tags: oracle

the question is as the title
at the oracle19c
why a user that only has [create session]privilege,but it can alter session like this:
step1:sqlplus / as sysdba
  create user TESTUSER identified by TESTUSER;
  grant create session to TESTUSER;
step2:sqlplus TESTUSER/TESTUSER 
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9';
  (why this user can alter session succussfully?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-SESSION.html#GUID-27186B28-7EFC-4998-B1ED-2B905CC0211B

> Prerequisites
>
> To enable and disable the SQL trace facility, you must have ALTER
> SESSION system privilege.
>
> To enable or disable resumable space allocation, you must have the
> RESUMABLE system privilege.
>
> **You do not need any privileges to perform the other operations of this
> statement unless otherwise indicated.**